# Conditional ruby platform specification in Gemfile

Tags: ruby, heroku, rvm, jruby, bundler

I'd like to take advantage of the heroku feature to specify my Ruby version in the Gemfile, per https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku. However, while I want to run JRuby on heroku, I want to be able to do some of my development on CRuby. The problem is that I get the following complaint whenever I try to run anything when the ruby specification in my `.ruby-version` file differs from what's in the Gemfile:

```
Your Ruby engine is ruby, but your Gemfile specified jruby
```

Is there any way that I can avoid this problem without having to modify my Gemfile while in CRuby? In particular, can I make the specification of ruby in the Gemfile conditional on something such that this complaint will go away in development, but it will still take effect for heroku (and not mess up travis either).

I tried to constrain the gem specification to the production group with:

```
group :production do
  ruby ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.9'
end
```

but that had no effect in development.

**Update**: Realizing that the Gemfile is "just ruby", I inserted a standard ruby `if` statement based on the existence of an environment variable I saw was available on Heroku but not elsewhere (i.e. `DYNO`), but I'd still be interested in whether there is an approach to doing this that's more mainline.

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
#ruby=1.9.3
source 'https://rubygems.org'
if ENV["JRUBY"] || RUBY_PLATFORM == "java"
# https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions
ruby '1.9.3', engine: 'jruby', engine_version: '1.7.10'
else
ruby '1.9.3'
end
```

NOTE: first comment is for RVM since it can get confused when parsing the ruby declaration